# найти с помощью xpath элемент <div class="recaptcha-checkbox-border" role="presentation"></div>

Tags: xpath

```html
<div id="rc-anchor-container" class="rc-anchor rc-anchor-normal rc-anchor-light">
  <div id="recaptcha-accessible-status" class="rc-anchor-aria-status" aria-hidden="true">Пройдите проверку reCAPTCHA.. </div>
  <div class="rc-anchor-error-msg-container" style="display:none"><span class="rc-anchor-error-msg" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
  <div class="rc-anchor-content">
    <div class="rc-inline-block">
      <div class="rc-anchor-center-container">
        <div class="rc-anchor-center-item rc-anchor-checkbox-holder"><span class="recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked rc-anchor-checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" id="recaptcha-anchor" tabindex="0" dir="ltr" aria-labelledby="recaptcha-anchor-label">
        <div class="recaptcha-checkbox-border" role="presentation"></div>
        <div class="recaptcha-checkbox-borderAnimation" role="presentation">
        </div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinner" role="presentation"></div>
        <div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinnerAnimation" role="presentation"></div>
        <div class="recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark" role="presentation"></div></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

---

div внутри iframe, код выше не знаю как исправить

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=2&amp;k=6Lc2AqYUAAAAAHWF74dHG5Vt9jtr13ZzKjCeetIu&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly9pbmZsdWVudGlhbC5jbzo0NDM.&amp;hl=ru&amp;v=75nbHAdFrusJCwoMVGTXoHoM&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=gah2099ehk13" width="304" height="78" role="presentation" name="a-9iuyb9nn6ltc" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox">
```

Comment: дак найдите, никто не против. а если помощь какая-то нужна, то приложите код, в котором написано как вы пытались решить эту задачу, и поясните в чем проблема.

Answer (score 0):

ищем div в любом месте дерева, у которого есть эти два атрибута с заданными значениями

```
//div[@class="recaptcha-checkbox-border" and @role="presentation"]
```

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class="recaptcha-checkbox-border" and @role="presentation"]"}